# Docker Volumes mounting issue

Tags: linux, permissions, docker, volumes

I am trying to dynamically mount a volume from the container to the host and it works but there is a hitch.  I am using the following command:

```
    docker run -it --name Test1 -v $HOME/.myapp_configs/specificConfig.txt:/bin/specificConfig.txt:rw docker-image /bin/bash
```

The issue lies in that if the mount point on the host does not exist the docker command creates it but assigns it `root:root` rather than `$USER:$USER` like I would expect.  I gather that this is more than likely a direct result of the namespace mapping issue that has been identified with Docker.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can force the host mount point to be created with the appropriate permissions? i.e.

```
    drwxr-xr-x. 3 $USER $USER  31 Aug 21 15:02  ~/.myapp_configs/specificConfig.txt
```

instead of...

```
    drwxr-xr-x. 3  root  root  31 Aug 21 15:02  ~/.myapp_configs/specificConfig.txt
```

Thanks,

Bruce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about making sure the file exists before running the container?

the command could look like:

```
test -f $HOME/.myapp_configs/specificConfig.txt || touch $HOME/.myapp_configs/specificConfig.txt
docker run -it --name Test1 -v $HOME/.myapp_configs/specificConfig.txt:/bin/specificConfig.txt:rw docker-image /bin/bash
```

explanation:

- `test -f <some file>` will have exit status `0` if the file exists
- `||` will execute the following command only if the previous command exit status is different than `0`
- `touch <some file>` modify an existing file modification time, or (and this is our case) create an empty file

Of course, if inside your container lies some code that acts differently whether the **file exists** or not, then you would have to adapt that code to check if the **file is empty** instead.

Comment: I had considered that one.  The only issue is that I am using a docker-compose file to orchestrate the starting of multiple containers.  As far as I can tell, there is no way to execute a command on the host from the compose file.  I may have to resort to writing an install script that must be executed prior to the end user trying to execute the code within the containers.  Although your answer didn't quite meet my needs it is a great answer for the normal case.  I guess I'm just abnormal.  :-)

Comment: Upon further research this currently is the only solution.  Thanks for your help.